# Will user rating removed if app purchase is cancelled on playstore

Tags: android, google-play, rating

I got an app at playstore, yesterday I get a bad rating (1 Star) but not of any error inside that app. It is no problem for me to handle bad ratings, because this gave me some feedback and shows me that I have to modify my app. But in that case the user hadn´t read the desription in playstore and inside the apps manual.

This user complains that my app is downloading dropbox if the dropbox app is not installed. But this is not possible without user confirmation and a warning before. Also this is described in App discreption at Playstore, so it is no suprise and this bad rating is just unfair.

I asked the user if he wants his money back, if yes I will cancel the purchase. My question is, will be that rating also removed from playstore if the app purchase is cancelled? I can´t get no information about this, this is not described anywhere in the developers guide or anywhere else. If somebody knows this I would be thankful if he/she tells me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, get used to unfair ratings. It sucks but this just happens, depending on how big the application **it could happen a lot**.

If someone doesn't like the color, not enough warnings, too much warnings, etc etc. Theres always a reason for someone to give a bad rating.

What to do about it?

Make a great app and get more and more better ratings.

What I found on your topic of removing ratings when uninstalling:

**Uninstalling the reviewed app does not seem to remove one's review. (Which makes sense, I guess.)**

Here is some extensive information about it:
[How do I remove a review I've written from the Android Market app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16836/how-do-i-remove-a-review-ive-written-from-the-android-market-app)

Google doesn't seems to allow to remove reviews at all: 
[Issue 16483: Android Market doesn't allow removing an existing application's rating and comment.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16483)

**Tips:**

- Make sure you warn people in application description that you require dropbox. Not just warn in-app. This might also be the reason for low ratings because people do not expect it.
- If the user would like so, cancel the purchase / refund anyway. This might give incentive for the user to change his rating before uninstalling. And gives you a good name.

Comment: +1 for `get used to unfair ratings`

Comment: I know right? When you first launch an app, and there's a bug in it or something. Boom so many low ratings. And you have to fight your way back to the top :)

Comment: Many thanks for Your fast reply. The use of Dropbox is also described in the app desription on Playstore, so it is no suprise. I can live with bad ratings if I had done anything wrong, this would be no problem. All other users from this app gave me 4 or 5 stars, so all are glad with the use. It is just this one user, If a user is unsatisfied I will allways offer him to get the money back

Comment: No Problem, I wish you good luck with your app and many good ratings!